# How to apply different sharey for rows in a MxN Matplotlib figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have been trying to generate a **2x3 figure** using `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots` wherein the first and second rows use `plot` and `loglog` commands, respectively.

Accordingly, I try to configure `subplots`, so that plots within the same row share the same y-axis.

However, the `loglog` y-axis (the latter row) appears in the `plot` y-axis (the former row).

Could you please advise us a viable configuration, if possible?

An [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example) with a random data set may be shown as follows:

```
plt.clf()

data = np.arange(0.01, 20.0, 0.01)

f, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 3, sharey=True)

for i, ax in enumerate(axarr[0].flatten()):
    ax.plot(data, np.exp(-data / 5.0))

for i, ax in enumerate(axarr[1].flatten()):
    ax.loglog(data, np.exp(-data / 5.0))

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

results in:

[image]

Comment: `ax.loglog` is roughly equivalent to `ax.plot` followed by `ax.set_xscale("log"); ax.set_yscale("log")`. Since the y axes are shared, this will then apply to all shared axes.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for:

```
f, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 3, sharey='row')
```

From the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html), pass these values to `sharex` or `sharey`:

- `row`: each subplot row will share an x- or y-axis.
- `col`: each subplot column will share an x- or y-axis.

Answer (score 0):

I now devised a *terrible* way of configuring such a behaviour:

```
plt.clf()

data = np.arange(0.01, 20.0, 0.01)

f, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 3, sharey=False)

for i, ax in enumerate(axarr[0].flatten()):
    ax.plot(data, np.exp(-data / 5.0))
    if i > 0:
        ax.set_yticklabels([])

for i, ax in enumerate(axarr[1].flatten()):
    ax.loglog(data, np.exp(-data / 5.0))
    if i > 0:
        ax.set_yticklabels([])

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

resulting in:

[image]

Comment: You loose the sharing here. The idea would be to only share the y axes of each row, not all of them.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yeah... :/ That's correct. Thanks for indicating it.